# Dynamic Drop Down Menu Problems

Tags: php, sql

I have an SQL query that I am trying to create a drop down menu from using the following code:

```
<?php 
    echo "<select name='Food'>";

    while ($temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($FoodQuery)
    { 
        echo "<option value="$temp['foodID']">$temp['food_name']</option>"; 
    }

    echo "</select>"; 

?>
```

But for some reason I keep getting errors when I try to run the page. I made sure the SQL query is working correctly so I'm not sure why it's not displaying.

Comment: Missing parenthesis, and have a look at [strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) to learn how they are concatenated : `"<option value=\"" . $temp['foodID'] . "\">" . $temp['food_name'] . "</option>";`

Comment: Thank you, I don't usually program in PHP so I didn't know you had to concatenate the strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few issues with your code.

First, you should copy the errors here to your question. This will solve *some* of your problems, but there may be others revealed by the error messages you aren't including.

1. The while loop doesn't have the necessary closing `)`.
2. The echo inside the loop is malformed.

   - You have incorrectly nested quotes.  You cannot nest a `"` inside a string that is encapsulated by `"`
   - I do not believe you can interpolate an array variable ( `echo "$myArray['key']"` ) I've modified to concatenate instead.

Here's the code, with revisions, to fix those errors:

```
echo "<select name='Food'>";
// Need to close the while condition with a closing )
while ($temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($FoodQuery))
{ 
    // The original echo will NOT work as is
    // echo "<option value="$temp['foodID']">$temp['food_name']</option>";
    // revised echo to properly output
    echo '<option value="' . $temp['foodID'] . '">' . $temp['food_name'] . '</option>'; 
}

echo "</select>";
```

Comment: You can interpolate array vars in double quoted strings, but needs curly brackets, and becomes a bit more cryptic... : `echo "<option value=\"{$temp['foodID']}\">{$temp['food_name']}</option>";`

Answer (score 0):

You have miss one ). It should be like that;

```
while ($temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($FoodQuery))
    { 
        echo "<option value=".$temp['foodID'].">".$temp['food_name']."</option>"; 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but now I have this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$temp' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' `

Comment: I've edited my answer. Now your Parse error will be fine.

Comment: The parse error may be fixed, but now your HTML is invalid.  You haven't enclosed the "value" in quotes....

Answer (score 0):

This:  `while ($temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($FoodQuery)`

Should be: `while ($temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($FoodQuery))`

This: `echo "<option value="$temp['foodID']">$temp['food_name']</option>";`

Should be: `echo "<option value=\"$temp['foodID']\">$temp['food_name']</option>"`

Or as an alternative that is clearer:

`echo "<option value=\"$temp['foodID']\">" . $temp['food_name'] . "</option>"`